# glibc detected *** ./testArray: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000

Tags: c++

I am having a problem in which my code is executing but then leads to a core dump, the capacity is 10. Here is the area of code that I believe is causing the problem, any tips?

```
Array& Array::operator+=(int value)
{
    if (eltsInUse == capacity) {
        cout << "\nElements in use: " << eltsInUse;
        cout << "\nCapacity : " << capacity;

        capacity++;
        arrayCount++;
        int* temp = new int[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            temp[i] = ptr[i];
        }

    } else {
        //cout<<"\nElements in use: "<<eltsInUse;
        cout << "\nCapacity : " << capacity;
        ptr[eltsInUse] = value;
        eltsInUse++;
        cout << "\nElements in use: " << eltsInUse;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your function return when `(eltsInUse==capacity)` is true?

Comment: Please [edit] and post a [mcve]

Comment: `return *this;` probably should be before the last `}` and not in the else {} block.

Comment: You also never save `temp` anywhere.  The memory it points to is leaked when the `if` block is exited.  You need to `delete[] ptr; ptr = temp;` after your copy loop.

Comment: @KamilCuk -- Answer:  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Well I was trying to get it to return *temp in this case but I ran into some trouble doing so

Comment: @chern You should be returning `*this`, regardless of the `if` statement, and regardless of any error(s) you may be encountering.

Comment: @chern _"ran into some trouble"_, well that's not a good problem description.

Comment: And when the guy hangs with slithy toves in the wabe, they know a good problem description when they see it.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thank you that solved the issue I was having.